# Vaadin RequestDispatcher don't lead to JSP file in webapp dir

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, vaadin

I've done my java web app in Java EE with HttpServlet and JSP. I normally map my Servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/main")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

I do my servlet stuff and would like to pass data to JSP file like this:

```
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

The main.jsp is in my web app folder (I use IntelliJ Idea).

The question is, I've initially made my UI with Vaadin 8. Using following:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@CDIUI("users")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Vaadin extends UI
```

and then override init.

Now I would like to add a single HttpServlet and override doGet and then call the dispatcher to forward data to jsp. Here's the problem adding Vaadin somehow broke the path to tsp, as jsp does not display, instead a standard vaadin

> Request was not handled by any registered handler.

appears, I know the servlet was mapped properly as the servlet starts and does work, what does not work is the running the JSP file.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to implement yet a `WebFilter` to process `JSP`. Your dispatcher forwards the request but it is then a request that is again handled by some filter by Vaadin I guess. Also I am not sure if you need any servlet and/or dispatcher (not sure what your actual use is).

Anyway, with `WebFilter` it is possible to intercept this processing. Check the following example

```
@WebFilter(filterName="jspFilter", urlPatterns="*")
public class JspFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            String path = hreq.getPathTranslated();
            if(path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jsp")) {
                try(Writer writer = response.getWriter();
                    Reader reader = new FileReader(path) ) {
                    processJsp(reader, writer);
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) { /* TODO: handle exception */};
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { /* TODO: handle exception */};
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // forward to filter chain by default 
    }
    @Override public void destroy() {}
    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
        throws ServletException {}
}
```

This filter checks all request. If `URI` (here checked from translated/absolute path) is ending with `.jsp` it is processed with `processJsp(reader, writer)` that you might want to implement to do the forwarding to `JSP` parser or so.